# What's the alternative to defining an as-yet-undefined variable with let inside an if-statement block?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment

Immediately before calling a function with a certain name, I would like to declare it (with a fallback definition), **if it does not already exist**:

```js
if (typeof myFunction === 'undefined') {
  
  let myFunction = () => console.log('Warning: myFunction() has not been defined.');
}

myFunction();
```

But, *of course*, `let` has block scope, so despite giving `myFunction()` a fallback definition inside the `if statement`, `myFunction()` remains undefined outside the if-statement-block.

---

The simplest solution is to use `var` (which does not have block scope) instead of `let`:

```
var myFunction = () => console.log('Warning: myFunction() has not been defined.');
```

Is that the recommended approach? Or am I missing something more conventional?

---

**N.B.** *How can it be that I don't know whether this particular function is or is not yet defined (either with `let`, `const` or `var`)?*

Because I am post-processing a user-generated script which may or may not include that function definition and needs to:

- provide a fallback, if it is not yet defined; or
- do nothing, if it is

Comment: How about ternary operator? `let fun = typeof fun !== 'undefined' ? fun : () => console.log('fun() not defined')`;

Comment: I thought about that approach. The issue there is, if `fun` is already defined, I cannot then redefine it.

Comment: @Rounin with a ternary operator you are not redefining the `fun` if it's already declared. If it is, then you just assign `fun` to `fun`

Comment: You cannot have two statements beginning with `let fun` in the same script. Note that the user _may_ have already declared `fun`. This is a catch, in case they have not.

Comment: @Rounin - Indeed, or even a `let myFunction` and a `var myFunction`.

Comment: @Rounin Ah you're right, I don't know what I was thinking. The ternary operator in the form I suggested would not work at all >.<

Comment: No worries, @Sebastian. I went through exactly the same thought process, tried exactly the same thing and had exactly the same epiphany.

Comment: You're talking about "*a fallback definition*", but I can't see that anywhere in your code?

Comment: The fallback definition is inside the if-statement block. It only gets assigned to the variable if the variable does not already have a function assigned to it.

Comment: I think you would find benefit from handling data relevant to the function as your truthy value first instead of the function itself. This method--without much context--comes across as causing future problems since the objective of calling a function is generally to handle/generate data.

Comment: @Rounin Are you talking about a global variable then? Otherwise I can't see how you wouldn't know whether the variable has a function value, or that you don't know how it was declared.

Comment: I am post-processing a user-written script. They can explicitly state: _My callback has the name `myCustomCallbackz`_ but they're not obligated to. If they omit such an explicit statement, their callback will be assumed to be `myCallback`. If they don't confirm that their callback has a custom name _and_ they also haven't defined `myCallback` then `myCallback` **will** need to be defined somehow or the script parser will hit an error and stop.

Comment: @Rounin Let me guess that you don't want to involve an EcmaScript parser (like part of a transpiler) but are just looking for a simple append-only or prepend-only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typeof` to check whether the variable has already been defined, which doesn't care about un-declared variables.

Then, instead of trying to maybe-declare the variable with the custom name, just declare a *new* variable with your own chosen name that will hold either the existing function or the fallback function, and then use that own variable for the call to the function:

```
{
  const __the_callback = typeof myFunction == "function"
    ? myFunction
    : function fallback() { console.log("warning …"); };

  …
  __the_callback();
}
```

Just make sure that `__the_callback` doesn't collide with the user-chosen name.

Comment: Outstanding. Very well done indeed. You just stole a green tick from @T.J.Crowder. I am in admiration and very grateful to both of you, so I'll let the pair of you fight it out between yourselves.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say your approach using `var` is your best bet **in this very, very specific situation**:

```js
if (typeof myFunction === 'undefined') {
  
  var myFunction = () => console.log('Warning: myFunction() has not been defined.');
}

myFunction();
```

Again, this is a very specific situation, and probably one of the very few valid use cases for `var` that's left (possibly *the* only one). There's just no reliable way to use `let` (or `const`, etc.) to declare a binding (loosely, variable) in a scope when you don't know whether or how it's already defined.

The only other semi-viable solution would be to just assign to it, but that would be specific to global scope, and would fail in strict mode.

`var`'s the answer here I think.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, @T.J.Crowder. I almost never use `var` these days. On discovering above that `var` has a functionality which cannot be mimicked, I don't know whether to be despondent or delighted.

Comment: @Rounin - LOL. Take heart from the idea that modules will make even this last remaining use case vanishingly rare... :-)